# Add an incremental number sequence in SQL INSERT SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query to insert values from one table to another table as below.

```
 INSERT into Workflow_CustomFormColumns     
    (CustomFormId
     ,ColumnNumber
     ,ColumnTitle
     ,ColumnType
     ,ColumnListValues
     ,IsRequired,ColumnWidth
     ,Calculation)
 SELECT ColumnNumber
    ,ColumnTitle
    ,ColumnType
    ,ColumnListValues
    ,IsRequired
    ,ColumnWidth
    ,Calculation
 FROM Workflow_CustomFormTypeColumns
 WHERE CustomFormTypeId=66 
    and ColumnNumber>43
```

Now for the `CustomformID` in `WorkFlow_CustomformColumns` I need to add values which increment from 250 to 300

Comment: Does your select returns `50` rows?

Comment: Is CustomformID identity column?

Answer (score 8):

You *can* do this with `row_number()` in the `insert`:

```
INSERT into Workflow_CustomFormColumns(CustomFormId, ColumnNumber, ColumnTitle,
              ColumnType, ColumnListValues, IsRequired, ColumnWidth, Calculation
             )
    SELECT 249 + row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as CustomerFormId,
          ColumnNumber, ColumnTitle, ColumnType, ColumnListValues, IsRequired, 
          ColumnWidth, Calculation
    from  Workflow_CustomFormTypeColumns
    where CustomFormTypeId = 66 and ColumnNumber > 43;
```

However, it is hard for me to think of a situation where you would really want this.  Instead, yo would typically make `CustomerFormId` and `identity` column and let the database assign unique numbers to the id.

Comment: I would say situations in which you want to handle the assignment of unique keys in your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

If CustomFormId is identity column then we can use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` to specify a new seed value by using `RESEED new_reseed_value` as below before Inserting data:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.Workflow_CustomFormColumns', RESEED, 250);
```

[Check DEMO here.](http://rextester.com/UOI91992)